# How to alter the path of login page?

Tags: 8, routes

I want to alter the path of login page, /user/login, to /ulogin.  How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Can I ask why you would want to change this?

Comment: To add security so they cannot easily access this login

Comment: This wouldn't add any security at all.

Comment: Why? Is this okay to access by anyone? I think this is important

Comment: What difference does it make if they don't have credentials? It is a public route no matter what you change it to. You should be enforcing strong password policies, failed login throttling and other methods instead if you are worried about that.

Comment: So is it okay? It cannot be easily to hack by anyone else?

Comment: I don't understand what you are getting at - how is it going to be hacked? Changing the URL is not going to prevent people from getting to a login form.

Comment: Okay this is my scenario. I have site made in drupal and i already make custom login page. I dont alter the existing login.

Comment: You mentioned you tried to do this?  What did you try?  Also edited the title.  You want to change the path not the route.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use module [Rename Admin Paths](https://www.drupal.org/project/rename_admin_paths)

> This module allows you to:
>
> rename path like '/admin/...' to '/something/...' rename path like
>   '/user/..' to '/something else/..' It can be effective against
>   registration spam bots or malicious people.
>
> This small module just implements hook_outbound_alter and
>   hook_inbound_alter to rename paths. A settings form allows to choose
>   replacement term for "admin" and "user".

Comment: Can't believe I've never heard of this module before, nice find.

Comment: this is right, but i want programmatically alter the path i think i need to make new question for this.

Comment: Late comment, but won't this prevent /new-path/reset from working when a User tries to reset their password?